# How to get the field definition by name of related objects in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to retrieve the field of related objects of a model by name.  For example if Book has a ForeignKey field to Author called author, I would like to be able to something like:

```
field = 'author__name'
Book._meta.get_field(field).verbose_name
```

It is general purpose so that string *author__name* is not known in advance -- I can't hardcode the fields or traversal.  Furthermore, it may span more than one relation like *author__address__city* if there was a fk to an Address model on the Author.

_meta.get_field() returns:

```
MODEL has no field named FIELD
```

When I try such a field name with fk traversal.  Django must have ways of doing this as these traversals must be done internally all the time, but I could not find how in the docs or looking into the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your lookup by the double underscore and then loop over the parts looking up the field on the model each time

```
lookup = 'author__name'
parts = lookup.split('__')
model = Book
for part in parts:
    field = model._meta.get_field(part)
    if field.many_to_one:
        model = field.related_model
    else: # TODO: handle other relationships
        print('Not handled field', field)
        break
```

This only handles ForeignKeys for now